# what does this mean: "jQuery('> li', this)"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how this jQuery plugin works: http://codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery

In the plugin there is this line at the beginning:

```
 if(jQuery('> li', this)) {
```

I know what

```
ul > li
```

means: it means select all li whose direct parent is a ul.  But what does '> li' mean?  I ran:

```
$('> li')
```

but it returns

```
[]
```

even though I have plenty of nested unordered list HTML on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't use it.** The docs advise that you shouldn't use at as it will be soon deprecated.

***From http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/***

> **Note:** The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.

---

But to answer, it effectively uses the element(s) from which the selector is called as the left hand operand of the *child-selector*.

Comment: lots of correct answers here, but I chose this one because the extra deprecation tip was the tie breaker.

Answer (score 5):

The 2nd parameter to the `jQuery` function is the context.

```
jQuery('> li', this)
```

Is the same as:

```
jQuery(this).find('> li')
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as `$(this).children('li')`. It's basically saying "use `this` as the context for the selector (`> li`)".

Answer (score 1):

its jsut like `ul > li` except that in this case you are replacing the `ul` part with the current context which is `this`. So whatever `this` is in the scope of that call that is the element you are resolving the `> li` to.

So for example:

```
var ele = $('ul#someId');
var list = $('> li', ele);


var list2 = $('ul#someId > li');

// list is the same as list2
```

Answer (score 1):

It will look for `li` element in the immediate children within `this` element where `this` can be a jQuery object or DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

The selector is looking for any immediate `<li>` children in the context of the `this` DOM element